# QScrollbar->setValue() does not work on first click of push button

Tags: c++, qt5

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I am really stuggling with finding a solution to this bug. I am using a QScroll area and push buttons to enable a user to jump to set coordinates of an image, which is inside a QLabels pixmap. The push buttons clicked signal connects to the set value slots of both the horizontal and vertical sliders, using coordinates (scroll bar set values) stored in a structure.

Some of my set values of coordinates are zoomed out and therefore do not have a vertical scroll bar visable (despite my setting scrollbaralwayson as an attempt to fix this issue).

The problem is, when say I go from an image without a vertical scroll bar, then click a button that calls an image that needs vertical scrolling, and call set value, the scroll bar appears but is not scrolled. Pressing the button a second time moves the slider to the correct position.

I know this has something to do with the vertical scroll bar not being present at the time of the first click (as I am going from an image that doesn't require one).

Can anyone help? The code is large and spread out, but here are the relevant parts. I even tried turning the functions into signals to prevent blocking but that didn't work either.

```
// Handles zooming the image to the correct level. This is a slot.

void MainWindow::resizeImage(double xScale, double yScale)
{
  ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image.scaled   (xScale,yScale,Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation)));
}

// Handles moving the scroll bars to the correct positions. This is a slot.

void MainWindow::adjustScrollBar(int dx, int dy, double xFactor, double yFactor)
{
  ui->imageScrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(dx * xFactor);
  ui->imageScrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(dy * yFactor);
}

// Handles a push button click, from a button group.
void MainWindow::buttonClick(int id)
{
  int index = (id -1); // 0 indexed structure

  emit scaleImage(detailviewX, detailviewY);

  // Acquire view Coordinates from model
  viewInfo tmp = list[index];
  int x = tmp.xCoord;
  int y = tmp.yCoord;

  int xBar = ui->imageScrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->maximum();
  int yBar = ui->imageScrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->maximum();

  if(xBar != 0 && xBarDetailview != 0) // If any of the bars are 0 I cannot work out factor as division by 0 doesn't help.
  {
      xFactor = (xBar / xBarDetailview);
  }

  if(yBar != 0 && yBarDetailview != 0)
   {
      yFactor = (yBar / yBarDetailview);
   }

     emit adjustScrollBar(x,y,xFactor,yFactor);
   }
```

Would greatly appreciate any help, as I am sure this has come up before but its hard to search for this specific issue.

Regards,

Comment: try calling the relevant function on page load

Comment: Do you mean emit the adjust scroll bar signal inside the scale image slot? might try that.